# Order amount credit memo partial refund not correct

Tags: creditmemo, edit-order, refund, magento-1.9.2.0, partial-invoice

Unfortunately, I have a issue with magento 1.9.2.0.

I made a partial refund credit memo for a customer. However, the total order amount is wrong. How can i fix this issue?

[image: Total order amount issue]

I found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/66862/custom-total-allow-partial-refunds) and [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105642/programatically-create-partial-invoice-has-totals-issue) as well, but don't know if that is the best way to fix this issue.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

---

Update: still no solution found after a month.

Here is the English version of image which helps to understand the question.
[image]

Comment: Can you update the question with some useful information like: custom modules you are using now, results of your research, last made changes (before the problem was found)

Comment: hey can you upload image pic in english

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau no new modules or components are added since oct/nov 2015. So the problem was existing for a longer time already.

Comment: can you come down for a chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40048/order-amount-credit-memo-partial-refund-not-correct

Comment: We have a similar problem with Magento 1.9.2.4. Sometimes a second creditmemo with partial refund for the same order includes the subtotal amount of the first creditmemo. Do you have a solution already?

Comment: Updating MSP may fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in the 2.2.1 version of the MSP module. MSP is aware of this issue and have an updated version which you can get through their support.

Credits goes to René [Creditmemo Grand Total does not include Tax](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92842/creditmemo-grand-total-does-not-include-tax)